# How do i use UI components in front-end in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, frontend, order-grid

I want to show orders grid in my account section in `Front-End`. I have extended `luma` theme.

I know it is possible to show `admin grid` in Front-End but, I don't have a breakthrough. Please assist me on how do i show `admin grid` in front-end. I want to show it in `My Account` section of the customer account.

Comment: For forms it makes more sense, for grids why not just create a table using the same class names?